# Why didn't Sasuke have the Rinnegan in the movie "The Last: Naruto the Movie"?

Tags: naruto

If Sasuke had his Rinnegan in *Naruto Shippuden*, wouldn't he still have the Rinnegan even after the war?
Then in *Boruto*, he has it permanently and when out of chakra goes down with no tomoe Rinnegan; still having the Rinnegan activated.

Answer (score 0):

Well if I'm correct, he did have the rinnegan, but it wasn't shown all that much due to how they made his hair appear.

Though in moments the animators could've forgotten to draw it. They did have mistakes like that in the movie.

[image]